# Dynamically build display for JSON-Data and JSONschema

Tags: javascript, html, json, frontend, jsonschema

I have a `JSON Schema` which describes the data I want to display.

```
{
    "title": "BeautifulDataRequest",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "DateOfRequest": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "PeopleRequested": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "JourneyType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "AccommodationDate": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Request": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have `JSON-Data` I want to display. The `JSON` can contain additional fields which are not described in the `JSON schema`, but I only want to display the values described in this schema.

The schema and the data can vary depending on the data type.
Since there are a lot of different schemata I am looking for something that can "create a display dynamically depending on the schema".

I already worked with [JSONEditor](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor), but this editor is for changing the schema, more than displaying the data. I can simply display the data by setting all fields to read only, but I think that is kind of awkward.

Sample data:

```
{
    "Id": "9be37e98-bc35-4aa5-8c74-39ea76415db5",
    "UserId": "c7c76272-e6f3-e811-93fc-005056b22eda",
    "TempId": null,
    "UserTypeName": null,
    "StoreCode": "fdsdf",
    "CurrentStepCode": "Done",
    "StoreAssignedName": "",
    "CreateDate": "2018-11-30T10:05:25.867",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "AdditionalData": {},
    "Type": {
        "Id": "c7c76272-e6f3-e811-93fc-005056b22eda",
        "Name": "Request"
    },
    "DateOfRequest": "17.11.2018",
    "PeopleRequested": "2",
    "JourneyType": "Doppelzimmer",
    "Request": "Nachfrage zur Reise",
    "AccommodationDate": "Insel Rügen – Perle der Ostsee"
}
```

To put it in a nutshell:
I have JSON-data which is described by a JSON-schema.
I want to display this data based on the JSON-schema.
The front end is HTML with bootstrap2 and JavaScript available.

Question:
Does anybody know a way/(JavaScript)library to dynamically display JSON-Data described by `JSON-Schema`?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of  your jsonData

Comment: How do you want to display the data? As a table? As a json? else?

Comment: I added an example dataset to the question.I would prefer to display the data as a  simple table with the property names as column names and the values as cell value.

Comment: JSON Schema is for validation and annotation of JSON data. It is not for filtering data. Simply, you need to write your own code to do this. There's no automated "JSON Schema to HTML table" thing... JSON Schema is far more complex than your example here.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll work with _.pluck to remove all uneeded properties from the data and then create a table with the JSON data left :)

Comment: Yes, or you can simply loop over your schema properties to get the data values from your json data and build the table in the same loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var schema = {
    "title": "BeautifulDataRequest",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "DateOfRequest": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "PeopleRequested": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "JourneyType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "AccommodationDate": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Request": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
};

var sampleData = [{
    "Id": "9be37e98-bc35-4aa5-8c74-39ea76415db5",
    "UserId": "c7c76272-e6f3-e811-93fc-005056b22eda",
    "TempId": null,
    "UserTypeName": null,
    "StoreCode": "fdsdf",
    "CurrentStepCode": "Done",
    "StoreAssignedName": "",
    "CreateDate": "2018-11-30T10:05:25.867",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "AdditionalData": {},
    "Type": {
        "Id": "c7c76272-e6f3-e811-93fc-005056b22eda",
        "Name": "Request"
    },
    "DateOfRequest": "17.11.2018",
    "PeopleRequested": "2",
    "JourneyType": "Doppelzimmer",
    "Request": "Nachfrage zur Reise",
    "AccommodationDate": "Insel Rügen – Perle der Ostsee"
}, {
    "Id": "1",
    "UserId": "2",
    "TempId": null,
    "UserTypeName": null,
    "StoreCode": "fdsdf",
    "CurrentStepCode": "Done",
    "StoreAssignedName": "",
    "CreateDate": "2018-11-30T10:05:25.867",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "AdditionalData": {},
    "Type": {
        "Id": "c7c76272-e6f3-e811-93fc-005056b22eda",
        "Name": "Request"
    },
    "DateOfRequest": "test",
    "PeopleRequested": "test",
    "JourneyType": "test",
    "Request": "test",
    "AccommodationDate": "test"
}];

function matchSchema (samples, schema) {
  var dataset = [];
  samples.forEach( sample => {
    // Deep clone schema (may use lodash or underscore)
    var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, schema);
    _.findKey(schema.properties, (value, key) => {
      if (_.has(sample, key)) {
        // You may validate type here
        clone.properties[key] = sample[key];
      }
    });
    // Add clone to dataset
    dataset.push(clone);
  });
  return dataset;
}

var result = matchSchema(sampleData, schema);
var $table = $('#result-table tbody');
console.log(result);

// Draw table
result.forEach(item => {
  var row = $('<tr/>');
  _.each(item.properties, (value, key) => {
    var column = $('<td/>').text(value);
    row.append(column);
  });
  $table.append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/Underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<table id="result-table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```